# Change types for error checking in c function arguments?

Tags: c, types, error-handling

I've been trying to handle errors in a simple c Library I'm writing. What's the best practice to check for argument errors (or typos) ? Let's say I have a function like this :

`int foo (size_t maxSize);  // (the int returned is an error type)`

Then let's say `foo` goes on to create an array of `maxSize` elements. My problem is this: if by mistake someone uses `foo` with a negative number, then this number is interpreted as a `size_t` and may become very large without warning:

`printf ("zu", -10);     // 4294967286 on my machine`

The program compiles without error or warning, `foo` tries to create a HUGE array, the program stalls at runtime, and there is no immediate way to find that `foo` is the cause (my soul).

How should this be properly handled ? Should `foo` take a `long` which it casts as a `size_t` after checking that it's positive ? (And then return the appropriate error ?). Or should `foo` keep `size_t` and not bother with users who don't follow `foo` signature ?

**EDIT ANSWER:**

Unanimously, keep the real signature `int foo (size_t maxSize)`otherwise it's misleading (since the max of `size_t` **is** a valid argument). Let the user handle it, maybe helping him through the docs.

Comment: if you want to be safe, you can use an explicit bounds check and report the error somehow (return value? assertions even?)

Comment: So ideally you'd like a compile-time warning for code that calls `foo` with an arg that the compiler knows is negative?  Or (maybe too noisy), warn for implicit conversion from signed types to the type of `foo`'s arg?

Comment: Many compilers supply a warning when passing a signed type to an unsigned type.  The user of your code can use that to prevent "may become very large without warning:"

Comment: A `size_t` cannot hold a negative number by definition.

Comment: BTW Your compilers should have warned about `printf ("zu", -10);` passing an `int` to "zu" which is curiously missing a `%`.  IMO, even your own compilations do not have warnings sufficiently enabled.  Start there.

Comment: You might (or might not) want to take a leaf out of the optional but normative Annex K of the current C standard (ISO/IEC 9989:2011) which defines a type `rsize_t` (restricted `size_t`) and a maximum value `RSIZE_MAX` which is used to help prevent such overflows.  You might decide on a maximum value you'll allow that's big enough for the foreseeable future but small enough to allow you to spot such problems.  You might set your limit `MAX_TSIZE` to a value such as `SIZE_MAX / 4`, or maybe more restrictive still on 64-bit systems.  (Note that `<stdint.h>` reserves names ending `_MAX`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question for your library is what is the largest size array that `foo` should create?  Is passing the maximum size of `size_t` an error?  If not then your library can't tell between an erroneous call and a legitimate call that wants a very large array to be created.  If you can't tell whether an input is invalid then you should treat it as valid.  The users of your library are responsible for catching these errors.

Comment: gcc `-Wall -Wextra` doesn't warn for `foo(-10)`.  There is an option to warn for that, but `-Wsign-conversion` is too noisy even for `-Wextra`.  See it with a constant arg and an `int` arg:  https://godbolt.org/g/cjqs3o

Comment: @PeterCordes: oops, my mistake, I'll edit to correct that.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. Yes: no reason why they couldn't max out the array so I guess `(size_t) -10` is a "valid" argument.

Comment: But... there is also no reason that is be THAT large, though. How about just a warning then ? The function is actually linked to a canvas (it's a graphic lib on top of cairo) and I guess I could work out a `maxSizeValue` based on the canvas size and just throw a kind warning if maxSize is considerably larger. I know I'll do it at least for MY use...

Comment: @nico7et8: Won't allocation just fail for sizes near the maximum value?  As long as your function cleanly returns an error, you're fine.  Actually printing anything would be weird.  Do you often have that kind of bug in your code?  I mean it's a size, even if you don't check the function signature, it should be obvious that passing a negative size won't be correct.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I've been on a quest to find an error handling system that's both practical and follows good practice, and what scared me about this particular error is how silent it is. The program just stalls without warning. But you're right. It's a size. Screw it.

Answer (score 1):

Extra code to check for args that have their high bit set seems excessive.  Overdoing it with defensive coding isn't great; it bloats the source and makes the binary slower.

People that use your library have a responsibility for not passing bogus args, like negative values as a size.

**Make sure your code doesn't crash or leak memory when an allocation fails, and that you return an error code in that case**.  I think that's the best approach.  If someone calls your function with a negative size, that's a major bug, and cleanly returning an error seems like the best way to make it easy for them to debug.

Comment: There is more to undefined behaviour than crash or memory leaks. There is no simple answer to the question and your statements do not apply for all situations or projects. High safety projects might rectify high defensive programming (with additional measures on failure). Just consider a 380V motor control.

Answer (score 1):

> Or should `foo` keep `size_t` and not bother with users who don't follow foo signature ?

Yes.

If negative values won't occur (aren't defined) for the input parameter in question, don't make it signed.

If you are nice you add to your docs to have potential production code be compiled with highest warning level.

Comment: Ok. In the docs then. It does seem cleaner otherwise the function signature stops making sens.

Comment: Follow up question: can the return value also be used for warning ? E.G., 0 is success, negative values are errors, and strictly positive values warnings? So someone who doesn't want to be bothered can just do : `if (foo (mySize) > 0) then {...}` to ignore warnings ?

Comment: @nico7et8: You are free to design your interfaces as you like. Still, sticking to `0` for success and `<0` for failure is common.

Answer (score -2):

The underflow of an unsigned integer (as is `size_t`) is e.g.: `UINT_MAX` for an `unsigned int`. They wrap around, so to say and that behaviour is defined in the standard:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding o subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new typ until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
>
> ISO 1999:2011 sec.6.3.1.3

The minimum size for `size_t` (described in ISO 1999:2011 7.19, in `stddef.h` Annex B.18)  is `SIZE_MAX` (described in ISO 1999:2011 7.20.3, set in `stdint.h` Annex B.19)

> Its implementation-defined value shall be equal to or greater in magnitude
>   (absolute value) than the corresponding value given below, with the same sign.
>
> ISO 1999:2011 7.20.3

but that is, as seen from the quote, only the minimum. What you can do is to implicitly trigger the conversion by e.g.:

```
size_t size_t_max = (size_t) -1;
```

And check the input `maxSize` of `foo` if it is of that size.

**Edited**

I do not know if it is my bad english or a basic misunderstanding of an industrial standard build by a committee with members from different companies all trying to get their special interest into the standard. That is the cause of a lot of compromises of the form "this and that is defined to have those values, but…" followed by a bunch of exceptions or, in the case of the standard for a programing language that can work very close to the hardware like C, a minimal value is defined and the rest is given out to the "individual implementation".

Not many people have a problem with that (except for the poor folks who have to build a compiler for that language ;-) ), it's what you get out of a committee, it's the expected outcome: only the lowest common denominator gets set in stone the rest is "implementation defined". In the pale face of the danger to repeat myself: there is no problem with that.

That leads to a lot of workarounds and other quirks, as with this question here.

The data type of `size_t` must be unsigned and able to hold numbers (for simplicity called "size" from here on) of up to 2^16 at least. That is all. The data type used for `size_t` might hold more, if necessary, even more than `SIZE_MAX`.

The C-standard is not written for the the x86er CPUs only but for much more, especially the hundreds of the small embedded processors you can buy now. Many of them have integer bit length different from 32 or 64. Some have 24 bit large integers, too, for example. With such a large amount of integers of different sizes the writes of the LibC for it can choose quite freely what they want to have for e.g. a `size_t`. They can also choose what value you want `SIZE_MAX` to have, e.g.: the minimum amount of memory you can offer for that processor.

That means that the only thing you can assume about the connection of `size_t` and `SIZE_MAX` is that the size the integer type used for `size_t` must be able to hold at least `SIZE_MAX`. That leads to the conclusion that the only C-standard compliant way to know if the argument `bar` of `foo(size_t bar)` is negative at runtime is to get the maximum size of the integer type used for `size_t` by intentionally causing an underflow (or wrap-around if you want) with `size_t size_t_size = (size_t) -1;`, a well defined behavior.

Just testing for `> SIZE_MAX` is not sufficient because `bar` could have been larger than `SIZE_MAX` but still not have been negative.

The still open question is, if a well defined behavior can be expected from passing a signed integer with a negative value as an argument defined to be unsigned. I would say: yes, because the conversion from signed to unsigned is well defined (in 6.3.1.8 and the actual conversion in 6.3.1.3).

Comment: Unsigned integers cannot overflow/underflow. They wrap. And `SIZE_MAX` is the **maximum** a `size_t` can represent, not the minimum! Not sure which problem you try to solve with `size_t_max`. What is your problem with the standard macro `SIZE_MAX`?

Comment: @Olaf Added a bit more explanation and excerpts from the current standard. Oh, and the limits are almost always minimums, as it is with `size_t` here, too. It is C.

Comment: The suffix `_MAX` should be clear enough. You seem to have missunderstood something. An implementation has to provide the **actual** limits it imposes. That's why the original file (for the standard integers) is called `limits.h`! Please read the standard, you are wrong!

Comment: And the section you cite is about conversion, not arithmetic behaviour. Behaviour for arithmetic out-of-range (UB, resp. wrapping) is defined elsewhere. And the macro `SIZE_MAX` is **not** defined in `stddef.h`, but `stdint.h` (you really should read 7.20).

Comment: Your citation of 7.20.3 is missleading due to the omission of the relevant part.

Comment: The file for the definition of  `SIZE_MAX` is in `stdint.h`, not `limit.h` (corrected myself, had it wrong, too). The standard says explicitly that&hellip;oh, I already quoted that part. There is nothing to misunderstand, the standard is unambiguous there.

Comment: What "relevant part" did I drop?

Comment: Did you even read my comments? "And the macro `SIZE_MAX` is not defined in `stddef.h`, but `stdint.h`"! It was you writing "The minimum size for size_t (..., in **stddef.h**"! I said _standard integers_ (i.e. _standard integer types_) when I mentioned `limits.h` as an **example** how the macros are to be treated, `size_t` is not a standard integer type). The same principleapplies for the other limit-macros, which are defined in other files **like** `stdint.h`! You apparently have missunderstood the intention of those macros.

Comment: Oh, and to be very exact: those macros do not define a _size_, but the **maximum representable values (the minimum for the `_MIN`-suffixed macros, for signed integer types only).